# Assembly x86: Copy data from register into memory location

Tags: memory, assembly, x86

I'm having a simple problem copying a char from register al into a variable called ErrorChars...

Do I have to dereference the destination as [ErrorChars]? Is this a decent solution to scanning a buffer, finding the errored chars within the buffer, and placing them in a string, so that I can print them as one item?

```
 SECTION .data                   ; Section containing initialized data                                                                                                           

    ErrorChars:             db "", 10
    ErrorCharsLen:          equ $-ErrorChars

    ; ... 

    mov al, byte [ebp+ecx]      ; copy current byte of Buffer into al                                                                                                            
    mov byte ErrorChars, [al]   ; copy byte at al into ErrorChars
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mov byte ErrorChars, [al]   ; copy byte at al into ErrorChars
```

ErrorChars is your memory operand, not al. So yes, it should be in brackets and not al.

```
mov [ErrorChars], al   ; copy byte in al into ErrorChars
```